# Select multiple values but only if they are not blank

Tags: xml, xpath

Given this simple XML document,

```
<root>
    <mode value="foo" icon="billing.png" />
    <mode value="bar" />
</root>
```

How do I select @value and @icon but only if @icon is present? I know that I can do

```
/root/mode/@value | /root/mode/@icon
```

But that still selects foo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
/root/mode[@value and @icon]/@value | /root/mode[@value and @icon]/@icon
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
/root/mode/[string(@icon)]
```